# How to set Jquery Toggle default show or hidden use html class control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I using Jquery Toggle to show my tree menu.

But I want to use HTML to control which sub-menu is 'actived'

How to let the '.actived' toggle show default?

```js
$('.show_more').click(function () {   
  $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
});

$(function(){  
  $('.show_more').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <ul class="level3">
    <li><label class="show_more actived">Bootstrap</label>
      <ul class="nav-list tree bullets">
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><label class="show_more">Bootstrap</label>
      <ul class="nav-list tree bullets">
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this in your css

```
.tree {
  display: none;
}

.actived+.tree {
  display: block;
}
```

For `+`  target the next immediate sibling element

```js
$('.show_more').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('actived')
});
```

```css
.tree {
  display: none;
}

.actived+.tree {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>


<ul class="level3">
  <li><label class="show_more actived">Bootstrap</label>
    <ul class="nav-list tree bullets">
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><label class="show_more">Bootstrap</label>
    <ul class="nav-list tree bullets">
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```